# Removing code duplication in C#

Tags: c#, code-duplication

I have many if and else statements and I am wondering how I can make it short and sweet. This function checks if the answer the user input into the textbox is the same as the answer in the (hidden) datagrid. If it is the same add 1 to correctAnswer - which calculates how many correct answers the user has correct (vice versa for wrong answer)

```
bool firstAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[0], textBoxQ1);
        if (firstAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label1.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool secondAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[1], textBoxQ2);
        if (firstAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label2.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool thirdAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[2], textBoxQ3);
        if (thirdAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label3.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool fourthAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[3], textBoxQ4);
        if (fourthAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label4.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label4.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool fifthAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[4], textBoxQ5);
        if (fifthAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label5.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool sixthAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[5], textBoxQ6);
        if (sixthAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label6.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label6.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool seventhAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[6], textBoxQ7);
        if (seventhAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label7.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label7.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool eighthAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[7], textBoxQ8);
        if (eighthAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label8.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label8.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool ninethAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[8], textBoxQ9);
        if (ninethAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label9.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label9.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        bool tenthAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[9], textBoxQ10);
        if (tenthAnswerCorrect == true)
        {
            label10.Text = "correct";
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            label10.Text = "incorrect";
            wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
        }
        label11.Text = ("YOU HAVE SCORED " + correctAnswers + " OUT OF 10");
        label12.Text = ("YOU HAVE " + wrongAnswers + " QUESTIONS WRONG");
```

The code WORKS its just repetitive

EDIT:

This function just calculates the correct and incorrect answers. I have another function which checks if the answer the user input into the textbox is the same as the answer in the (hidden) datagrid

This is the code for that function:

```
 private bool CheckAnswer(DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow, TextBox textBox)
    {
        string correctAnswer = dataGridViewRow.Cells["answer"].Value.ToString();
        string givenAnswer = textBox.Text;

        bool isCorrect = string.Equals(correctAnswer, givenAnswer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        return isCorrect;
    }
```

As I said. Its working but its just repetitive which is not a good sign.

EDIT:

This is the new C# code I am using which is eliminates the code duplication, however I encountered an exception when I tweaked it a bit.

```
 List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox> { textBoxQ1, textBoxQ2, textBoxQ3, textBoxQ4, textBoxQ5, textBoxQ6, textBoxQ7, textBoxQ8, textBoxQ9, textBoxQ10 };
        List<Label> labels = new List<Label> { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10 };
        bool temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            temp = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[i], textboxes[i]);
            if (temp == true)
            {
                labels[i].Text = "correct";
                correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;

            }
            else
            {
                labels[i].Text = "incorrect";
                wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
            }
            label11.Text = ("YOU HAVE SCORED " + correctAnswers);
            label12.Text = ("YOU HAVE SCORED " + correctAnswers);
        }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The line:

```
 temp = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[i], textboxes[i]);
```

Comment: You have bug in the second block: `if (firstAnswerCorrect == true)`.

Comment: what type of bug? It seems to work fine for me

Comment: Take a look at `if` condition of the **second** block. It is using `firstAnswerCorrect` variable instead of `secondAnswerCorrect`.

Comment: ahh yes I see now. Thank you

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate if asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the value of `i` when you are encountering the exception ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make one `List<TextBox>` and one another `List<Label>` like below:

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>{textbox1, ....}
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>{label1, label2, ....}
bool temp;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    temp = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[i], textBoxes[i]);
    if (temp)
    {
        labels[i].Text = "correct";
        correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        labels[i].Text = "incorrect";
        wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in `label[i].Text = "incorrect";` --> `labels[i].Text = "incorrect";` But in general you can name your variable whatever you want. Just make sure you are using that variable. If you are having any problem again just let me know what is the problem

Comment: oops! countered an error when I tweaked it a bit. It was working fine for a bit but then when I added the "you have scored *** out of *** " bit, an exception has been thrown. Check the bottom of the question which I edited.

Comment: Becareful with indexes, make sure you have 10 textboxes and labels in Lists. Furthermore make sure you have  10 rows in dataGridView1. They need to have the same size. At the for loop you can change the max index from 10 to `textboxes.Length`

Comment: stupid error I made. I try to calculate the total without retrieving the questions from the database and putting it into the datagrid. Thanks again

Comment: Dont worry, it is a common mistake :p

Answer (score 1):

May try to reduce repetition in the following way:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>() {
    textBoxQ1,
    textBoxQ2,
    ...
    textBoxQN
};

List<Label> labelList = new List<Label>() {
    label1,
    label2,
    ...
    labelN
};

for(int i = 0; i < textBoxList.Count; i++) {
    bool answerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[i], textBoxList[i]);
    labelList[i].Text = answerCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect";
    correctAnswers += answerCorrect ? 1 : 0;
    wrongAnswers += !answerCorrect ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd store all the answer textboxes and correct/incorrect answer labels in an array, like `Label[] answerLabels` and `TextBox[] answerTextBoxes`. These arrays should be properly ordered, i.e. `answerLabels[0]` and `answerTextBoxes[0]` should correspond to the 1st question, `answerLabels[1]` and `answerTextBoxes[1]` should correspond to the 2nd question and so on.

Thereafter this becomes a single for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < answerLabels.Length; i++) {
    bool answerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridView1.Rows[i], answerTextBoxes[i]);
    if (answerCorrect == true)
    {
        answerLabels[i].Text = "correct";
        correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        answerLabels[i].Text = "incorrect";
        wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution would be changing everything to strings instead of Booleans. This way you won't need any `if` statements. Just `label1.Text = firstAnswerCorrect` which equals (string) either `"correct"` or `"incorrect"`

And for the function you would just return `"correct"` or `"incorrect"`

Hope this helps.